# Alt+F2 maps to volume down instead of run command

Tags: centos, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Dell laptop and "Alt+F2" invokes a volume-down operation instead of "run command".  The correct mapping for Alt+F2 does appear in my keyboard shortcut settings, so I think that the key combination is getting caught prior to reaching the desktop manager.

What can I do to keep this key combination from being captured so as to allow me to use Alt+F2 to run the launcher?

Comment: Are you using laptop? `Fn` key? Locked/unlocked `Fn`?

Comment: For me, the best 'run' is a Win+R combination. It is hardcoded on Windows, and easily modified on almost any WM on Linux. Since I have to use both OSes - the same combination is an obvious choice.